# How to get file last modified time with Perl 5.004 and no modules

Tags: windows, file-io, perl

I have a standalone version of Perl for Windows (5.004) that does not include any modules. I want to run a script to check the last modified time of several files.

I could use `File::qstat`, but that module doesn't exist (the copy of Perl is in version control, so it can be used by people who do not have [ActivePerl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl) or [Strawberry Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Perl) installed).

It seems like there are three options:

1. Figure out how to put a newer, more functional, standalone Perl installation into version control
2. Just add the File::Stat module somehow, and do `use lib` (does that work on 5.004?)
3. Use some built-in functions included in 5.004 for Windows to get the file status.

How can I do this?

Comment: [perldoc -f stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html)

Comment: Good gawd. I have siblings younger than Perl 5.004.

Comment: @friedo: there are even people still deploying perl 4.036 out there. Only $DEITY knows why.

Comment: File::stat is just an OO layer over the builtin stat

Comment: File::stat was first introduced in 5.004. Not only is your copy of Perl ancient, it's broken. :-/ Perl merged its Unix and Windows versions in 5.6.0, so who knows what you're using. Windows support was pretty bad before 5.6 and a lot is probably terribly broken. I'd really, really, REALLY suggest upgrading.

Comment: and I thought only my company is using the oldest version of Perl (5.8.5). Now I feel young ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -le '$file=shift or die;print scalar localtime((stat($file))[9])' file
```

See [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) .

Comment: Ah ha...I see what I did.  When I ran it using `File::stat` and a newer perl, it returns an object, so when I commented that out and tried it with old perl, it didn't work.  Just using stat as an array works fine.  That's what I get for overthinking it and not RTFMing I guess!  Thanks for the quick (and simple) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth are you stuck using Perl 5.004?  I have source from Perl 5.5.3 dated in 1999, so Perl 5.004 is likely to be several years older than that.  (I found source for Perl 5.004_04 after all; the latest timestamp in that was 1997-10-15 06:46.)  So, that's about 15 years old.

The `stat` function is likely to exist and do the job you need.